# FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR missing bracket error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

The Xcode compiler keeps on telling me that I am missing a bracket before the F in FATAL (error commented out), but I can't make sense of this. Can you tell me what's missing or needs to change?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    // 1
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    // 2
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Location"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // 3
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor  = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    // 4
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *foundObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (foundObjects == nil) {
        FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error); // Expected ']' (F in FATAL highlighted)
        return;
    }

    // 5
    _locations = foundObjects;
}
```

Comment: Is FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR #defined? You probably are missing a bracket somewhere there if so.

Comment: Thank you; I looked in the define and there was indeed a missing bracket. Thank you!

Comment: Please answer your own question with the solution you found and then mark. Thanks.